# SQL SERVER Passing in multiple NULL Parameters in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Write a SQL Stored Procedure (pr_GetOrderSummary) to return a summary of orders from the data in the Northwind database. You may NOT use Dymanic SQL to solve the problem.

The results should be able to be filtered by specifying parameters:
•   Date of the Order (@StartDate and @EndDate)
•   Nullable Parameter to filter for a specific Employee (@EmployeeID)
•   Nullable Parameter to filter for a specific Customer (@CustomerID)

The columns to be returned are:
•   EmployeeFullName (TitleOfCourtesy + FirstName + LastName)
•   Shipper CompanyName
•   Customer CompanyName
•   NumberOfOders
•   Date
•   TotalFreightCost
•   NumberOfDifferentProducts
•   TotalOrderValue

The results should be grouped by:
•   Order Day (i.e. grouped by day)
•   Employee
•   Customer
•   Shipper

```
Some helpful tests:
`exec pr_GetOrderSummary @StartDate='1 Jan 1996', @EndDate='31 Aug 1996', @EmployeeID=NULL , @CustomerID=NULL`

`exec pr_GetOrderSummary @StartDate='1 Jan 1996', @EndDate='31 Aug 1996', @EmployeeID=5 , @CustomerID=NULL`

`exec pr_GetOrderSummary @StartDate='1 Jan 1996', @EndDate='31 Aug 1996', @EmployeeID=NULL , @CustomerID='VINET'`

`exec pr_GetOrderSummary @StartDate='1 Jan 1996', @EndDate='31 Aug 1996', @EmployeeID=5 , @CustomerID='VINET'`
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pr_GetOrderSummary 
@StartDate datetime, 
@EndDate datetime, 
@EmployeeID int = NULL, 
@CustomerID varchar(50) = NULL
AS 
BEGIN
Select  
o.OrderID,
ei.TitleOfCourtesy + ' ' + ei.FirstName + ' ' + ei.LastName AS 'EmployeeFullName',
sid.CompanyName as 'Shipper CompanyName',
cid.CompanyName as 'Customer CompanyName',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), o.OrderDate, 106) AS 'Date',
o.Freight,
od.Quantity,
(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount) AS 'TotalOrderValue'
FROM Orders o
Inner Join Shippers sid 
on o.ShipVia = sid.ShipperID
Inner Join Employees  ei
on o.EmployeeID = ei.EmployeeID
Inner Join Customers cid
on o.CustomerID = cid.CustomerID
Inner Join [Order Details] od
on o.OrderID = od.OrderID 
WHERE
o.OrderDate >= @StartDate and 
o.OrderDate <= @EndDate and
(o.EmployeeID is null or o.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID) AND
(o.CustomerID is null OR o.CustomerID = @CustomerID);
END
```

The above is my stored procedure that i created it works when all the parameters are included but it does work when one ore more of the parameters are NULL

Comment: Do you mean "it does NOT work"? What `NULL` parameters cause the SP to fail?

Comment: The NULL Parameters do not return any records, the SP does not faiil

Comment: What parameters do you set to `NULL` when you get no records

Comment: You may want to use LEFT JOIN's on the ones that can be null e.g. replace the Inner Join with LEFT JOIN for the Employess and Customers

Comment: @Alex The EmployeeID and CustomerID is set to NULL simultaneously

Comment: @Andrew I tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: Should the null check perhaps be done on the variable (instead of the column)? `o.EmployeeID is null or o.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID`

Comment: @ALex Thank you so much for pointing that out to me. Everything works perfectly now. (@EmployeeID is null or o.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID) AND
(@CustomerID is null OR o.CustomerID = @CustomerID);